# how find a max value with comma separeted values and ids into a table

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

i have some problem with this query, to find max item_cost into this table

```
  OrderID     |    item_ids| item_cost
  ---------------------------------------------------------
  1             1,2,3      22,88,77
  2             2,4        83,26
```

i find this function

```
SELECT * FROM scb.invoice_out 
where FIND_IN_SET('2',item_ids)
```

but the answer is the complete row and i  only need the max (item_cost) of the single item

```
 OrderID     |    item_ids| item_cost
 ---------------------------------------------------------
 1             1,2,3      22,88,77
 2             2,4        83,26
```

somebody with the same problem ?

Comment: I didn't quite understand, you want to select the row, that in one of the separated values in item_cost column is the maximum value of all rows?

Comment: if the id was 2 the MAX(item_cost) is 88

Comment: Once you get the row back, you should process it with PHP to get the highest value, this will keep the SQL simple and it won't do more than it's supposed to (get data from the DB) and PHP will do what it's supposed to as well !

Comment: you have to fetch and loop through the values or you have to sort the values before insert into the table so the max value is always exist at the end. Then use substring with position of comma and string length then you can achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A mysql solution for your Question Could be

```
select
  max(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`item_cost`, ',', numbers.n), ',', -1)) as max_id
from
  (select 1 n union all
   select 2 union all select 3 union all
   select 4 union all select 5) numbers INNER JOIN invoice_out
  on CHAR_LENGTH(`item_cost`)
     -CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(`item_cost`, ',', ''))>=numbers.n-1
where 
    FIND_IN_SET('2',item_ids)  
order by
  OrderID, n
```

Comment: @VladimirEncina If this answers your question mark it as answer :)

Comment: i'm new so i don't have reputation :(

Comment: You will see a `tick mark` right under '0' on left hand side you click on that and this will be selected as answer :)